# Изменение стиля элемента при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, как можно сделать чтобы при нажатии на ссылку менялся стиль у элемента? Если возможно, киньте какой-нибудь пример. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам именно надо на чистом JS? Тогда вот [простейший пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GXMk9/1/). Но если не принципиально важно, то на jQuery эти манипуляции делать проще и быстрее.

Comment: Мне желательно на jquery,спасибо за пример подскажите пожалуйста а как тоже сделать с visible ?просто надо один элемент скрыть а второй показать.

Comment: Если речь идет о двух элементах, то можно сделать [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8S8zv/), но если скрываться/показываться могут больше элементов, то этот способ не подойдет. Там уже надо делать проверки на то, какой элемент активный, какой открывать вслед за ним и т.д.

Comment: Вот я только что написал вариант,подскажите можно как нибудь сократить его или нет ?
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
$("#hidecent").click(function() {
    
$("#comcenter-friends").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#foter_space").css("width", "5px");
$(".cont_main").css("display", "inline-block");
$(".cont_main").css("width", "80%");
$(".cont_main").css("height", "2100px");
$("html,body").css("text-align", "center");
$("html,body").css("height", "100%");
});

}); 

</script>

Comment: Можно так:

    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#hidecent").click(function() {
            $("#comcenter-friends").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#foter_space").css("width", "5px");
            $(".cont_main").css({
                display: "inline-block",
                width: "80%",
                height: "2100px"
            });
           
            $("html,body").css({
                textAlign: "center",
                height: "100%"
            });
        });
    });

Comment: никогда так не делайте, 99.9% стилям место в css